# Docker bind mount preventing ability to checkout diff branch

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Compose for local development (WSL 2 backend enabled for Docker Desktop, all files stored in WSL filesystem). I have a few folders and a few specific files with host bind mounts so that changes get propagated back and forth when developing.

Here's what the volumes section of the containers config looks like the `docker-compose.yml`. "app" is an apache container and it shares these volumes with a phpfpm container since phpfpm is a reverse proxy for all php files in the project.

```
services:
  app:
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - app:/var/www/html
      - ../src/app/code:/var/www/html/app/code:cached
      - ../src/app/design:/var/www/html/app/design:cached
      - ../src/app/etc:/var/www/html/app/etc:cached
      - ../src/composer.json:/var/www/html/composer.json:cached
      - ../src/composer.lock:/var/www/html/composer.lock:cached

  phpfpm:
    volumes: *appvolumes
```

(the reason I've not just mounted the entire `src` directory is because it's a Magento project so there's over 85,000 files totaling over 1GB, a lot of which are generated on demand when developing, so performance was an issue - at least in WSL 1)

The issue is whenever I try to checkout a branch that has differences in the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files (i.e. having a new package / different version installed), `git checkout` fails with the following:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'composer.json': Device or resource busy
error: unable to unlink old 'composer.lock': Device or resource busy
M       composer.json
M       composer.lock
```

and what happens is it essentially uses the version of the previous branch (in this case `master`) while I'm now on the other branch `develop`. So they're modified in the git status since the file differs between the branches. At this point I can't switch back to master because it wants me to commit my "modified" changes. I also can't discard the changes to the files or stash them or do anything else because Docker is using them.

Even if I `docker-compose down` and remove the containers, Docker is still using the files, so I have to shut Docker Desktop completely down before I can switch back.

Should note that this only happens with these files, if I checkout a different branch that has differing files within the `src/app/code` directory, no issues.

Is there any way to propagate changes between these files without running into this issue? I'm running any composer commands within the container, not on the host.